# Convert function to MACRO

Tags: oracle, function, macros

I have customers who can have one or more accounts and each of these accounts can contain none or 1 or more transactions (debits or credits).

I currently have a function (get_customer_balance), which appears to be working. You can see from my test CASE below.

I want to update this function to take advantage of SQL_MACRO but when I swap out the working function with the SQL_MACRO function I get the following error:

ORA-64629: table SQL macro can only appear in FROM clause of a SQL statement

I've been struggling to try and get this working but have been unsuccessful. Can someone help me out with code that can utilize the MACRO and RETURN the customers balances.

Below is my test case and instructions on how to run the code successfully and reproduce the error. Thanks to all who answer.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (
CUSTOMER_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME,IS_ACTIVE) AS  SELECT 'L382059', 'Leo', 'Langford','Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'P382319', 'Tom', 'Micelli','Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'E379466', 'Bonnie', 'Winterbottom','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'X060162', 'Lisa','Saladino','Y'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Y331964', 'Sandy', 'Herring','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Z888555', 'Barbara', 'Broadwater','Y' FROM DUAL;

ALTER TABLE customers 
ADD CONSTRAINT customers_pk PRIMARY KEY (customer_id);

CREATE TABLE vendors AS
    SELECT level AS vendor_id,
       'Vendor ' || level AS vendor_name
    FROM   dual
    CONNECT BY level <= 3;

ALTER TABLE vendors 
    ADD ( CONSTRAINT vendors_pk
   PRIMARY KEY (vendor_id));

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS (
ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
CUSTOMER_ID, VENDOR_ID,
IS_ACTIVE) AS 
SELECT 'Z17ARWYYZRCU2Q2', 'P382319', 1, 'Y' FROM DUAL 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT '0T81Z07CS6LXQ7Z', 'P382319', 3, 'Y' FROM DUAL 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'YWYXC3Q5N9XZ7S', 'L382059', 1, 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '612ZKAQ66VA3W3', 'Y331964', 3, 'Y' FROM DUAL    UNION ALL 
SELECT 'BCHD9TW78W67S1D', 'Z888555', 3, 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT '0HLS87LDR1TE8WB', 
'X060162', 3, 'Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Z69AG7DKS37UYU',
'X060162', 3, 'Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'B17ARWYYZRCU2Q2', 
'X060162', 3, 'Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'THVQD6M9LR7AVK', 'E379466', 1, 'Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT '0Z76WT5NTLRZPTW',
'E379466', 1, 'Y' FROM DUAL;

ALTER TABLE customer_accounts 
ADD CONSTRAINT customer_accounts_pk PRIMARY KEY (ACCOUNT_NUMBER);

ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS ADD CONSTRAINT ca_customer_fk FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMER_ID) REFERENCES customers(customer_id);

ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS ADD CONSTRAINT ca_vendor_fk FOREIGN KEY (VENDOR_ID) REFERENCES vendors(vendor_id);

create table transactions (
     transaction_id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    account_number VARCHAR2(15),
    transaction_type varchar2(1) DEFAULT 'C',
    transaction_amount NUMBER(10,2),
     transaction_date DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE 
);

ALTER TABLE TRANSACTIONS ADD CONSTRAINT transactions_account_number_fk  FOREIGN KEY (ACCOUNT_NUMBER) REFERENCES customer_accounts
(account_number);

insert  into transactions(
account_number, transaction_type, transaction_amount, transaction_date)
SELECT 'Z17ARWYYZRCU2Q2', 'D', (LEVEL * 1250.50), date '2023-05-14' + level * interval '5 15:13' day to minute from dual
          connect by level <= 7
union all
SELECT 'Z17ARWYYZRCU2Q2', 'C', (LEVEL * 1175.75), date '2023-07-04' + level * interval '1 21:23' day to minute from dual
          connect by level <= 5
union all
SELECT '0T81Z07CS6LXQ7Z', 'D', (LEVEL * 1250.50), date '2023-02-14' + level * interval '3 15:13' day to minute from dual
          connect by level <= 17
union all
SELECT '0T81Z07CS6LXQ7Z', 'C', (LEVEL * 75.75), date '2023-02-04' + level * interval '2 21:23' day to minute from dual
          connect by level <= 11
union all
select '612ZKAQ66VA3W3', 'D', 555.25 * LEVEL, (DATE '2023-07-13' + 13/24) + (level * 2)  from dual 
    connect by level <= 25 
UNION ALL 
select '612ZKAQ66VA3W3', 'C', 555.25 * LEVEL, (DATE '2023-07-23' + 13/24) + (level * 2)  from dual 
    connect by level <= 20 
UNION ALL 
select 'BCHD9TW78W67S1D', 'D', 1125.25 * LEVEL, date '2023-01-23' + level * interval '1 1' day to hour from dual
          connect by level <= 11
union all
select 'BCHD9TW78W67S1D', 'C', 925.00 * LEVEL, date '2023-01-25' + level * interval '1 1' day to hour from dual
          connect by level <= 7
union all
SELECT '0HLS87LDR1TE8WB', 'D', (LEVEL * 1250.50), date '2023-05-04' + level * interval '1 15:13' day to minute from dual
          connect by level <= 7
union all
SELECT '0HLS87LDR1TE8WB', 'C', (LEVEL * 1175.75), date '2023-05-04' + level * interval '1 15:13' day to minute from dual
          connect by level <= 5
union all
SELECT 'Z69AG7DKS37UYU', 'D', ((LEVEL * 5) * 1750), date '2023-06-01' + level * interval '1 18:43:35' day to second from dual
          connect by level <= 15
union all
SELECT 'Z69AG7DKS37UYU', 'C', ((LEVEL * 5) * 1750), date '2023-06-11' + level * interval '1 15:23:49' day to second from dual
          connect by level <= 13
union all
SELECT '0Z76WT5NTLRZPTW', 'D', (LEVEL * 100.57), date '2023-04-02' + level * interval '1 4' day to hour from dual
          connect by level <= 5
union all
SELECT '0Z76WT5NTLRZPTW', 'C', (LEVEL * 25.26), date '2023-04-04' + level * interval '1 4' day to hour from dual
          connect by level <= 5
union all
SELECT 'THVQD6M9LR7AVK', 'D', (LEVEL * 250.10), date '2023-05-10' + level * interval '1 7' day to hour from dual
          connect by level <= 13
union all
SELECT 'THVQD6M9LR7AVK', 'C', (LEVEL * 133.11), (SYSDATE - LEVEL)  from dual
          connect by level <= 9;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION   get_customer_balance
(  i_customer_id   IN   customers.customer_id%TYPE
)
RETURN  transactions.transaction_amount%TYPE
IS
  v_balance   transactions.transaction_amount%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT SUM (
                 CASE  t.transaction_type
             WHEN  'C'
             THEN  -t.transaction_amount
             ELSE  t.transaction_amount
         END 
             )
  INTO   v_balance
  FROM   customer_accounts  ca
  JOIN   transactions       t  ON  t.account_number  = ca.account_number
  WHERE  ca.customer_id  = i_customer_id  -- one customer
  OR     ca.customer_id  IS NULL;         -- all customers

RETURN nvl(v_balance,0);
END  get_customer_balance;
/

/* WORKS */

SELECT C.CUSTOMER_ID,
       C.FIRST_NAME,
       C.LAST_NAME, 
       get_customer_balance(C.CUSTOMER_ID) AS balance
FROM   customers c
ORDER BY balance DESC;

========================
SWAP OUT FUNCTION HERE
========================

create or replace function get_customer_balance (
  i_customer_id in varchar2
) return clob sql_macro 
is
begin
  return q'[
   SELECT 
     SUM 
     (
       CASE  t.transaction_type
       WHEN  'C'
       THEN -t.transaction_amount
       ELSE t.transaction_amount
       END 
      )
   FROM  customer_accounts  ca
   JOIN  transactions       t  ON  t.account_number  = ca.account_number
   WHERE  ca.customer_id  = i_customer_id  -- one customer
   OR   ca.customer_id  IS NULL    ]';
end;
/

/* EXACT CODE DOESN'T WORK */

SELECT C.CUSTOMER_ID,
       C.FIRST_NAME,
       C.LAST_NAME, 
       get_customer_balance(C.CUSTOMER_ID) AS balance
FROM   customers c
ORDER BY balance DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as you were told - move function into a `from` clause, e.g.

```
  SELECT c.customer_id,
         c.first_name,
         c.last_name,
         (SELECT * FROM TABLE (get_customer_balance (c.customer_id))) AS balance
    FROM customers c
ORDER BY balance DESC;
```

I don't have database that supports macros so I ran this piece of code on apex.oracle.com (Oracle 19c) - here's a screenshot which illustrates it:

[image]

BTW, thank you for test case!

Comment: Littlefoot, thank you. FYI live SQL supports macros and you can use it for free if you like. Can I refrence the variable balance  and do something like balance > 20000, which based on my data should return only 2 rows.

Comment: You're welcome. As of referencing balance: yes, you can do that. A simple option is to use current query as a CTE (or a subquery), as you can't reference it *directly*, just by adding a WHERE clause to existing query.